# Help identifying connector type?

Tags: connector

Could anyone help me identify these male and female connectors? They're smd mount, I would guess molex, but Farnell shows way too many results to sift through.
Any lead is much appreciated!
I am also interested in what kind of crimps are used on the female side.

[image: connector]

Answer (score 1):

These are [Molex PicoBlade series](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoblade&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors).  The distance between pins (pitch) should be 1.25mm.

[image]

[image] Crimp terminal (on tape)

Comment: 53398-0671 for future reference.